# HTML5 Video Image

Tags: javascript, css, html

ok so I got my video background playing but how do I add my image over the background? something like this? image over video background I have been trying for weeks. also, my image doesn't show on top of the video. Any help?

[image]

```css
body, html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

video{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <video poster="Sample.jpg" autoplay="true" loop>
            <source src="background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="background.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>
            <img src="water%20boyz.png" width="100px">    
                
                
            </div>
```

Comment: try position absolute for image too and setting apropiate z-index.

Comment: I tried that still image doesn't  show

Comment: The solution proposed by @Panther should work. Update your fiddle and show us why it doesn't show? Is it because an incorrect URL is being referenced? Is the request to the image URL returning some kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

1) Set your container to `position: relative`.

2) Set both the video and image to `position: absolute`.

3) Freely move stuff around.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;

}

.container video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left : 0;
  width : 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border : red dashed 2px;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left : 40px;
  width : 100px;
  height : 80px;
  border : green dashed 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video poster="Sample.jpg" autoplay="true" loop>
    <source src="background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="background.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
  
  <img src="water%20boyz.png" width="100px">    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting negative(-) `z-index` to `video` will give you the desired output. Check below snippet for reference. Just change `video` css from `z-index: 1;` to `z-index: -99;`.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -99;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" autoplay="true" loop>
            <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/red">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
img {
z-index:0;
position: absolute;
display:block
width:100px;
height:100px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Fullscreen Video</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<style>
 *{
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.content {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 960px;
padding: 0 15px;
}

h1 {
margin: 60px 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
}

p {
margin: 0 0 30px 0;
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 1.5;
 }

.fullscreen-bg {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
.fullscreen-bg__video {
    height: 300%;
    top: -100%;
}
}

 @media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
.fullscreen-bg__video {
    width: 300%;
    left: -100%;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.fullscreen-bg {
    background: url('../img/videoframe.jpg') center center / cover no-
repeat;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
    display: none;
}
}   
</style>
```

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
        <source src="http://dev2.slicejack.com/fullscreen-video-demo/video/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://dev2.slicejack.com/fullscreen-video-demo/video/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="http://dev2.slicejack.com/fullscreen-video-demo/video/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <h1>Full screen HTML5 video background</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix te quidam commodo placerat. Mei ne dicunt minimum disputationi, purto everti adolescens id cum, quis veritus cotidieque eum ex. Ea eirmod atomorum posidonium sed, splendide dissentiunt an mel. Dolorem suavitate voluptatibus pro no. No duo conceptam cotidieque.</p>
     <img src="download.jpg"/>
</div>

</body>
```